# Changing the default alignment of a ragged array in ArrayPLot

Tags: plotting

I want to make the digits from this output to print starting from the rightmost column.

```
Array[Function[n,IntegerDigits[n,2]],5] // ArrayPlot[#, ColorRules -> {0-> Gray, 1 -> Black}, Mesh-> True, Background->None, Frame-> False]&
```

The first three rows should be

```
None (*white square*), None (*white square*), 1 (*black square*)
None (*white square*), 1 (*black square*), 0 (*gray square*)
None (*white square*), 1 (*black square*), 1 (*black square*)
```

The default plot shows

```
  1 (*black square*), None, None
  1 (*black square*), 0 (*gray square*), None
  1 (*black square*), 1 (*black square*), None
  ...
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `PadLeft[]`:

```
ArrayPlot[PadLeft[Array[Function[n, IntegerDigits[n, 2]], 5], Automatic, None],
          Background -> None, ColorRules -> {0 -> Gray, 1 -> Black},
          Frame -> False, Mesh -> True]
```

[image: right-aligned]

Comment: I came up with `digits = Array[Function[n,IntegerDigits[n,2]],5];
pad = Max[Length /@ Array[Function[n,IntegerDigits[n,2]],5]];
paddedDigits = PadLeft[#, pad, None]& /@ digits;
ArrayPlot[paddedDigits,ColorRules -> {0-> Gray, 1 -> Black, None-> White}, Mesh-> True ]` before your posting. Your solution looks nicer.

Comment: @and, in general `PadLeft[]` and `PadRight[]`, when applied to a ragged array, builds a rectangular array with the appropriate columns containing the padding element (taken to be `0` by default); in the case of `PadLeft[arr, Automatic, None]`, the padding element used is `None`, which is then rendered appropriately by `ArrayPlot[]`.

Answer (score 3):

Some magic for your entertainment:

```
Range[5] ~IntegerDigits~ 2 + 1 // 
  Block[{PadRight = PadLeft}, ArrayPlot[#, Mesh -> True]] &
```

[image]

Comment: A little spelunking should help with showing why this works. ;)

Comment: @J.M. It seemed logical that `PadRight` would be used to do the equivalent (but opposite) of what you did, and a `Trace` showed that it was.  This was the natural application.